# Is there any issue with the 6/3 wire being used on the 40amp circuit for the double oven?

Tags: wiring

I am installing a new Whirlpool Double wall oven and a separate cooktop range in a new remodeled kitchen (converted the carport into huge new kitchen).   When I installed the wiring, I thought the oven was going to be a 50 amp (based on research before the oven was purchased) and so I ran 6/3 wire for the oven and 8/3 wire for the cooktop. Now that I have the appliances purchased and in the kitchen ready to be connected, I can see that both of them are just 40amp. I have separate 40amp breakers in the box for them.  Is there any issue with the 6/3 wire being used on the 40amp circuit for the double oven?

Comment: Within reason larger wire are always good.  It is they just cost more(usually) and can be harder to work with.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 6/3 with a 40 amp breaker, just fine.

The breaker protects the wire.  Wire can be oversized to the protection of the breaker, but not undersized.

You are fine.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to mark the wire as 6/3 too, just so it's easy for some future person who might need a 50A circuit to know they can do it simply by swapping the breaker.